# Understanding Relational with ActiveRecord in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I understand SQL
I understand Database Methodology
I understand Rails
I don't understand ActiveRecord Relations

I have three models (simplified) that i created with rails g model and then performed a rake db:migrate with a mysql db.

```
Calendar
id: number
name: string

Event
id: number
title: string

Event_Tag
id: number
event_id
key: string
value: string
```

How would i perform a query for all events and retrieve all the event_tags for each so that i could build a JSON model with minimal queries?

```
Event
id: number
title: string
tags: [
    <key>:<value>,
    <key>:<value>,
    <key>:<value>,
]
```

I have tried this:

```
events = Event.includes(:event_tag).where("events.calendar_id" => params[:calendar_id])
```

Which i have seen avoids the N+1 query issue. And it performs 2 queries.

```
Event Load (47.1ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE `events`.`calendar_id` = 1

EventTag Load (46.3ms)  SELECT `event_tags`.* FROM `event_tags`  WHERE `event_tags`.`event_id` IN (1)
```

But when i inspect an event

```
eventHash = events[0]
```

i receive

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, title: "Test", calendar_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

Comment: Hi - what have you tried yourself (and how did it not work for you)?

Comment: Hi i updated the question with things i have tried

Comment: "And it performs 2 queries" and those two queries are...? 
:)

Comment: Removed and put in question

Comment: and how do you build the json? and where are you inspecting the event that you receive? and have you confirmed that that event has tags ? ;)

Just covering all the bases... it could be a silly little error :)

Comment: Also - comment code-formatting doesn't exist :P can you put any answers to my questions into your actual question please :)

Comment: cool so it looks like it is definitely pulling out the event tags. the options are: a) this event doesn't have any tags b) the json you are building isn't including them c) something else... but lets check those two first

Comment: The event does have tags. I ran the EventTag Load query against the db and got the proper result.

How do i retrieve the tag data from the result model?

As in is there an accessor method?

Comment: Well, that's a good question... can you show us the event model and the association that you wrote for event_tags :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ActiveRecord**

Although I don't know the behind-the-scenes workings of ActiveRecord, I do know it's what's called an [ORM (Object Related Mapping) system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (framework for SQL)

This means it gives you a series of methods to call, which it will then translate into the relevant SQL queries (`joins` etc)

---

**Associations**

[ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#) are basically glorified `join` statements - each time you call an object, and then reference its associated data, you will basically be calling two queries to ping two separate data tables.

The way AR works is to use the [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

I think your problem is best solved using an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) defined in your `Event` model:

```
#app/models/event.rb
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags, class_name: "EventTag"
end
#app/models/event_tag.rb
Class EventTag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@event = Event.find params[:id]
@event.tags.each do |tag|
   tag.name
   tag.value
end
```

---

If this helps, if you comment, I'll see about helping combine the `tags` into a JSON hash for you, although I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that exactly

Comment: With that association in place it is possible to do this: `Event.find(params[:id]).to_json(include: :tags)`. This will retrieve more information than needed, but it might help. It will add associated models as an array.

Comment: Technically you answered the question i had. How, when i receive the array of data do i pull the relational data from the result.

Nowhere in the documentation do they mention that it can be retrieved in the way you stated.

When i print out the result model it only shows the an event model but it doesn't show that i can pull the event_tags by calling event_tag

Comment: Hey panchal, which documentation were you looking at?

Answer (score 1):

The `includes` method in Rails eager loads the relationships into memory for quicker access so the application doesn't do all the N+1 queries.

So even though the relation doesn't show up when you inspect the code, if you access it thru the relation (e.g. `event.event_tag.key`) the application doesn't perform additional queries since the data is already present in memory.

Here's a really good article explaining eager loading in Rails (discusses `includes` and other useful methods `eager_load` and `preload` and how they're all related):  http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

As far as building the JSON object, it really depends on how you're going about that.  I'd imagine the most common libraries (e.g. jbuilder or active_model_serializers) would handle the relations query fine.

Comment: So i researched this and you are right pretty much exactly from the documentation. Which is why i chose to do it this way because events will eventually become 100+ records at a time. 

Eager loading was the way i wanted to do it. 

My question was that the array i get from the query seemed to only have Event models in them how would i retrieve the event_tag data.

I couldn't find in the doc that relational data could be retrieved like:

event_tags = events[0].event_tag